# Trying to properly prepend an element if the first letter of the first item doesn't start with a hyphen

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to see if the first letter of the first item, of each article category, starts with a hyphen, if not, then add element before first item(or other words, prepend element to item parent). I got some help in another question on detecting if the item starts with a hyphen, and I thought I could figure out the rest, but I have failed.

HTML: *removed, updated, and added below.*

jQuery: *removed, updated, and added below.*

I get an error `Unexpected identifier`. **FIXED, WAS CAUSED BY TYPO**

I have been trying various things for a few hours, other attempts just end up adding the element to every article, even if it already has a item with a hyphen.

In hindsight, I guess it doesn't matter if it's the "first item" or not, but must be first letter. I merely thought I would try to do it that way as a precaution. What really matters if a any item in the article > post-header > post-category-label starts with a hyphen, if not then add element.

In other words, a category is defined as a item that starts with a hyphen, and if a category doesn't exist, add one( `<span class="item">-Uncategorized</span>` ). However, only the first item can will be visible as the category, so -Uncategorized must be the first item.

I hope I didn't confuse anyone.

In my mind, the jQuery I am using should be working, but doesn't. How do we make this happen correctly?

**EDIT:** fixed the typo that fixed the error. However, now the script adds the element to every article, instead of just the article that needs it.

**EDIT**: the first example html I wrote didn't duplicate the problem, so below I copy & pasted from source, but edited out some data so that the problem can be duplicated.

HTML:

```
<article class="article" id="article-0" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Article">
  <div class="post-header">
    <a class="featured-image-link" href="#" id="featured-image-link-0" itemprop="thumbnailUrl">
      <time class="featured-image-timestamp" itemprop="datePublished">
        <span class="featured-image-timestamp-month">Dec</span>
        <span class="featured-image-timestamp-day">03</span>
      </time>
      <div class="featured-image-category">
        <span class="item">
          -Technology
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          add-snow
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          blogging
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          blogspot
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          feature
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          test
        </span>
      </div>
      <canvas class="add-snow" width="751" height="423"></canvas>
    </a>
    <a name="8075834726885144989"></a>
    <h1 class="post-title entry-title" itemprop="headline">
      <span>
        <a href="#">Article One</a>
      </span>
    </h1>
    <div class="post-info">
      post-info
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-body entry-content float-container">
    body content
  </div>
  <div class="post-footer">
    footer content
  </div>
</article>
<article class="article" id="article-0" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Article">
  <div class="post-header">
    <a class="featured-image-link" href="#" id="featured-image-link-0" itemprop="thumbnailUrl">
      <time class="featured-image-timestamp" itemprop="datePublished">
        <span class="featured-image-timestamp-month">Dec</span>
        <span class="featured-image-timestamp-day">02</span>
      </time>
      <div class="featured-image-category">
        <span class="item">
          add-prank
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          add-snow
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          blogging
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          blogspot
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          feature
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          test
        </span>
      </div>
      <canvas class="add-snow" width="751" height="423"></canvas>
    </a>
    <a name="8075834726885144989"></a>
    <h1 class="post-title entry-title" itemprop="headline">
      <span>
        <a href="#">Article Two</a>
      </span>
    </h1>
    <div class="post-info">
      post-info
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-body entry-content float-container">
    body content
  </div>
  <div class="post-footer">
    footer content
  </div>
</article>
<article class="article" id="article-0" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Article">
  <div class="post-header">
    <a class="featured-image-link" href="#" id="featured-image-link-0" itemprop="thumbnailUrl">
      <time class="featured-image-timestamp" itemprop="datePublished">
        <span class="featured-image-timestamp-month">Dec</span>
        <span class="featured-image-timestamp-day">01</span>
      </time>
      <div class="featured-image-category">
        <span class="item">
          -Technology
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          blogging
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          blogspot
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          feature
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          test
        </span>
      </div>
      <canvas class="add-snow" width="751" height="423"></canvas>
    </a>
    <a name="8075834726885144989"></a>
    <h1 class="post-title entry-title" itemprop="headline">
      <span>
        <a href="#">Article Three</a>
      </span>
    </h1>
    <div class="post-info">
      post-info
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-body entry-content float-container">
    body content
  </div>
  <div class="post-footer">
    footer content
  </div>
</article>
```

jQuery

```
$('.featured-image-category').each(function() {
  $('.featured-image-category .item:first-of-type').filter((index, item) => item.innerHTML.split('')[0] !== '-').parent().prepend('<span class="item">-Uncategorized </span>');
});
```

Also, here is a jsFiddle illustrating the problem: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/m76buL31/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by iterating through all the [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) and get the text using `.text()` then [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) the elements text retrieved since tags text might contain whitespaces characters, and to get the first character you can just use [`.charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) method, then we use that value in the if statement to check if the first character is `-` or not, here is a working snippet:

```js
$('.featured-image-category .item:first-child').each(function() {
  if($(this).text().trim().charAt(0) !== '-') {
    $(this).prepend('<span class="item">-Uncategorized </span>');
  }
})
```

```css
.add-snow {
  height: 0px;
}

article {
 outline: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
 padding: 10px;
}


article:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="article" id="article-0" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Article">
    <div class="post-header">
        <a class="featured-image-link" href="#" id="featured-image-link-0" itemprop="thumbnailUrl">
            <time class="featured-image-timestamp" itemprop="datePublished">
                <span class="featured-image-timestamp-month">Dec</span>
                <span class="featured-image-timestamp-day">03</span>
            </time>
            <div class="featured-image-category">
                <span class="item">
                    -Technology
                </span>
                <span class="item">
                    add-snow
                </span>
                <span class="item">
                    blogging
                </span>
                <span class="item">
                    blogspot
                </span>
                <span class="item">
                    feature
                </span>
                <span class="item">
                    test
                </span>
            </div>
            <canvas class="add-snow" width="751" height="423"></canvas>
        </a>
        <a name="8075834726885144989"></a>
        <h1 class="post-title entry-title" itemprop="headline">
            <span>
                <a href="#">Article One</a>
            </span>
        </h1>
        <div class="post-info">
            post-info
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-body entry-content float-container">
        body content
    </div>
    <div class="post-footer">
        footer content
    </div>
</article>
<article class="article" id="article-0" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Article">
    <div class="post-header">
        <a class="featured-image-link" href="#" id="featured-image-link-0" itemprop="thumbnailUrl">
            <time class="featured-image-timestamp" itemprop="datePublished">
                <span class="featured-image-timestamp-month">Dec</span>
                <span class="featured-image-timestamp-day">02</span>
            </time>
            <div class="featured-image-category">
                <span class="item">
                    add-prank
                </span>
                <span class="item">
                    add-snow
                </span>
                <span class="item">
                    blogging
                </span>
                <span class="item">
                    blogspot
                </span>
                <span class="item">
                    feature
                </span>
                <span class="item">
                    test
                </span>
            </div>
            <canvas class="add-snow" width="751" height="423"></canvas>
        </a>
        <a name="8075834726885144989"></a>
        <h1 class="post-title entry-title" itemprop="headline">
            <span>
                <a href="#">Article Two</a>
            </span>
        </h1>
        <div class="post-info">
            post-info
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-body entry-content float-container">
        body content
    </div>
    <div class="post-footer">
        footer content
    </div>
</article>
<article class="article" id="article-0" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Article">
    <div class="post-header">
        <a class="featured-image-link" href="#" id="featured-image-link-0" itemprop="thumbnailUrl">
            <time class="featured-image-timestamp" itemprop="datePublished">
                <span class="featured-image-timestamp-month">Dec</span>
                <span class="featured-image-timestamp-day">01</span>
            </time>
            <div class="featured-image-category">
                <span class="item">
                    -Technology
                </span>
                <span class="item">
                    blogging
                </span>
                <span class="item">
                    blogspot
                </span>
                <span class="item">
                    feature
                </span>
                <span class="item">
                    test
                </span>
            </div>
            <canvas class="add-snow" width="751" height="423"></canvas>
        </a>
        <a name="8075834726885144989"></a>
        <h1 class="post-title entry-title" itemprop="headline">
            <span>
                <a href="#">Article Three</a>
            </span>
        </h1>
        <div class="post-info">
            post-info
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-body entry-content float-container">
        body content
    </div>
    <div class="post-footer">
        footer content
    </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.post-category-label').each(function() {
  $('.post-category-label .item:first-of-type').filter((index, item) => item.innerHTML.split('')[0] !== '-').parent().prepend('<span class="item">-Uncategorized </span>');
});
```

you are missing a dot before "parent()"

Comment: It was a typo, but using this script, it add the element to every article, instead of just the articles that need it.

Comment: i tried your code in jsfiddle, and it seems like it is working as intended? https://jsfiddle.net/kazuryo/cj56m7uq/ 
unless i misinterpreted your question

Comment: Yes, I can confirm it is working as intended in the fiddle. I just got to figure why it is adding the element to every article in my template. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the HTML example to show the problem of the element being added to every article, instead of just the article that needs it. Which was the main problem. https://jsfiddle.net/m76buL31/3/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using `innerHTML` to get span content. Without using `.trim()` it will include white space too. So you can either apply `.trim()` before `.split()` or use `innerText`.

Probably it is good to use `.trim()` either way to make sure white space (at least at the start of the string) is removed and you can probably check for hyphen.

Here is an example:

```js
$('.featured-image-category').each(function() {
  $('.featured-image-category .item:first-of-type').filter((index, item) => {
    /* These will work too
     return item.innerText.indexOf("-") != 0
     return item.innerHTML.trim().split('')[0] !== '-';
    */
    return item.innerText.trim().split('')[0] !== '-';
  }).parent().prepend('<span class="item">-Uncategorized</span>');
})
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

article {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

time {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.item {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="article" id="article-0" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Article">
  <div class="post-header">
    <a class="featured-image-link" href="#" id="featured-image-link-0" itemprop="thumbnailUrl">
      <time class="featured-image-timestamp" itemprop="datePublished">
        <span class="featured-image-timestamp-month">Dec</span>
        <span class="featured-image-timestamp-day">03</span>
      </time>
      <div class="featured-image-category">
        <span class="item">
          -Technology
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          add-snow
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          blogging
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          blogspot
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          feature
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          test
        </span>
      </div>
      <canvas class="add-snow" width="751" height="423"></canvas>
    </a>
    <a name="8075834726885144989"></a>
    <h1 class="post-title entry-title" itemprop="headline">
      <span>
        <a href="#">Article One</a>
      </span>
    </h1>
    <div class="post-info">
      post-info
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-body entry-content float-container">
    body content
  </div>
  <div class="post-footer">
    footer content
  </div>
</article>
<article class="article" id="article-0" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Article">
  <div class="post-header">
    <a class="featured-image-link" href="#" id="featured-image-link-0" itemprop="thumbnailUrl">
      <time class="featured-image-timestamp" itemprop="datePublished">
        <span class="featured-image-timestamp-month">Dec</span>
        <span class="featured-image-timestamp-day">02</span>
      </time>
      <div class="featured-image-category">
        <span class="item">
          add-prank
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          add-snow
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          blogging
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          blogspot
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          feature
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          test
        </span>
      </div>
      <canvas class="add-snow" width="751" height="423"></canvas>
    </a>
    <a name="8075834726885144989"></a>
    <h1 class="post-title entry-title" itemprop="headline">
      <span>
        <a href="#">Article Two</a>
      </span>
    </h1>
    <div class="post-info">
      post-info
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-body entry-content float-container">
    body content
  </div>
  <div class="post-footer">
    footer content
  </div>
</article>
<article class="article" id="article-0" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Article">
  <div class="post-header">
    <a class="featured-image-link" href="#" id="featured-image-link-0" itemprop="thumbnailUrl">
      <time class="featured-image-timestamp" itemprop="datePublished">
        <span class="featured-image-timestamp-month">Dec</span>
        <span class="featured-image-timestamp-day">01</span>
      </time>
      <div class="featured-image-category">
        <span class="item">
          -Technology
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          blogging
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          blogspot
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          feature
        </span>
        <span class="item">
          test
        </span>
      </div>
      <canvas class="add-snow" width="751" height="423"></canvas>
    </a>
    <a name="8075834726885144989"></a>
    <h1 class="post-title entry-title" itemprop="headline">
      <span>
        <a href="#">Article Three</a>
      </span>
    </h1>
    <div class="post-info">
      post-info
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-body entry-content float-container">
    body content
  </div>
  <div class="post-footer">
    footer content
  </div>
</article>
```